# Filter pins and its value on a map with a searchbar

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to filter the pins on a map depending on what you write in the searchbar. So if you write for example: "Unit" then only the pins with the adress "Unit....(ed states)" will show up. I have started with some code but I am not sure how I should carry on. When I type something now every pin loads instead of the ones that match with the inputted text on the searchbar. I guess I have to use the filterfunction before I add the pins.

This is my startPage:

```
public StartPage ()
{
    searchBar.TextChanged += (sender2, e2) => FilterContacts(searchBar.Text);

    searchBar.SearchButtonPressed += (sender2, e2) => FilterContacts(searchBar.Text);
}
```

This is where the filter is happening. I get the data from my DB.

```
private  async void FilterContacts (string filter)
    {
        map.Pins.Clear ();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (filter)) {

        } else {

            var getItems = await phpApi.getInfo ();

            foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {

                theName = currentItem ["Name"].ToString (); //theName = string
                theAdress = currentItem ["Adress"].ToString (); //theAdress = String

                var theUserPosition = theAdress;
                Geocoder gc = new Geocoder ();
                Task<IEnumerable<Position>> result =
                    gc.GetPositionsForAddressAsync (theUserPosition);

                if (theAdress != null) {

                    IEnumerable<Position> data = await result;

                    foreach (Position p in data) {

                        var pin = new Pin ();
                        pin.Position = new Position (p.Latitude, p.Longitude);
                        pin.Label = theName;
                        pin.Address = theAdress;                    
                        map.Pins.Add (pin);

                        theAdress.ToLower ().Contains (filter.ToLower ());


                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Every time the user types you call FilterContacts, which loads data from your webservice and then geocodes each point.  You should really only do that once, and store the resulting data.  Also, you should clear the existing pins from the map before you filter.

Comment: Yeah I have a pin clear now in the start. I am not quite sure how you mean. Am I not doing that right now? When I start typing the filtercontacts starts. An example would be very appreciated.

Comment: TextChanged fires every time the user types - you are doing an expensive network request and multiple geocoding operations every time they type.  This is wasteful.  Instead, do this ONCE when the page loads.  Then when the user types you will just search through the data that is already loaded in memory.

Comment: So I load the DB (without adding pins of course) straight away when they reach the page. And with the string cointaining the DB info I add them into my filtercontacts function and add this: "theAdress.ToLower ().Contains (filter.ToLower ()); " //theadress is my string. Am I understanding you correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load the data and geocode it ONCE and store it; then only call the filter logic

```
public StartPage ()
{
    searchBar.TextChanged += (sender2, e2) => FilterPins(searchBar.Text);

    searchBar.SearchButtonPressed += (sender2, e2) => FilterPins(searchBar.Text);
}

// create a list to store our Pins 
List<Pin> myPins = new List<Pin>();

private async override void OnAppearing() {

  if (myPins.Count == 0) {
    myPins = await LoadData();

    filterPins(string.Empty);
  }
}

// load the data, geocode, store results
private async List<Pin> LoadData() {

  var pins = new List<Pin>();

  var getItems = await phpApi.getInfo ();

  foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {

    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder ();
    var pos = await gc.GetPositionsForAddressAsync (theUserPosition);

    foreach (Position p in pos) {

      var pin = new Pin ();
      pin.Position = new Position (p.Latitude, p.Longitude);
      pin.Label = theName;
      pin.Address = theAdress;                    

      pins.Add(pin);
    }     
  }

  return pins;
}

private  async void FilterPins (string filter)
{
  map.Pins.Clear ();

  foreach(Pin p in myPins) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter) || (p.Address.Contains(filter)) {
      map.Pins.Add(p);
    }
  }
}
```